# Java SWT Composite 1 px padding

Tags: java, swt

I use a GridLayout on my parent Composite and want to kill the 1px padding that is created while rendering the object. What is the parameter to change to get this part working? My composite is rendered like this

```
final Composite note = new Composite(parent,SWT.BORDER);
GridLayout mainLayout = new GridLayout(1,true);
mainLayout.marginWidth = 0;
mainLayout.marginHeight = 0;
mainLayout.verticalSpacing = 0;
mainLayout.horizontalSpacing = 0;
note.setLayout(mainLayout);
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: About what part are you talking?

Comment: Between the Grey border and the Blue box, there is a thin 1px White line. Somehow I want to remove it.

Comment: It's caused by `SWT.BORDER`. Use `SWT.NONE` to get rid of the padding.

Comment: So SWT.BORDER actually add 2px of border? One Grey and one White?

Comment: @Johnny000 Exactly. (At least that's the behavior for Windows 7)

Comment: @Johnny000 Are you happy with that as an answer?

Comment: Yes, is there is no way to get a "standalone" Grey border without a White line I'm happy with it..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SWT.BORDER` is causing your issue. On Windows 7 it will draw a border of 2px, one grey and one white. Use `SWT.NONE` to get rid of the border altogether.

If you really want a 1px grey border, you can add a `Listener` for `SWT.Paint` to the parent of your `Composite` and make it draw a border with the `GC`:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    final Composite outer = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    outer.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1, false);
    layout.marginHeight = 0;
    layout.marginWidth = 0;
    outer.setLayout(layout);

    Composite inner = new Composite(outer, SWT.NONE);
    inner.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
    inner.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    shell.addListener(SWT.Paint, new Listener()
    {
        public void handleEvent(Event e)
        {
            e.gc.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WIDGET_BORDER));
            Rectangle rect = outer.getBounds();
            Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(rect.x - 1, rect.y - 1, rect.width + 2, rect.height + 2);
            e.gc.setLineStyle(SWT.LINE_SOLID);
            e.gc.fillRectangle(rect1);
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

And here with green background:

[image]